# Logstash xml filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to store the following xml format data at once.

```
<title>name</title>
<destination>my name</destination>
<log>hi~ my name is taewoo!</log>
<date>2018-09-04T09:00:00</date>
```

However, each field is stored separately, creating three documents.

Below is the configuration file.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/usr/local/ELK/logstash-6.3.2/config/test1.xml"
        start_position => "beginning"
        type => "xml"
    }
}
filter {
    xml {
        remove_namespaces => true
        source => "message"
        xpath => ["/title", "title",
                  "/destination", "destination",
                  "/log", "log",
                  "/date", "date"]
        target => "doc"
        store_xml => true
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "t4"
#        document_type => "test"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "root123"

    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your file looks like? Using the [multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) plugin should be able to solve the problem most likely.

Comment: If you're using the multiline plugin, you should use a configuration similar to this one: `multiline {
       pattern => "$<title>"
       negate => "true"
       what => "previous"
     }`.